# Manipulating CSV data with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I'm having a problem with PHP - I have a CSV file that looks something like this:

Guest name, Category, Arrival, Departure, Rate

John Smith, Leisure, 01-04-10, 02-04-10, 150

Ann Watson, Private, 01-04-11, 02-04-11, 120

Now - there are thousands of rows. I need to group them by Category and then add Rate for all of Leisure, then all of Private etc.. so I can get the totals for each category.

I've managed to import CSV file with the following code:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('bookings.csv','r') or die("can't open file");
print "<table>\n";

while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,1024)) {
    print '<tr>';
    for ($i = 0, $j = count($csv_line); $i < $j; $i++) 
    {
        print '<td>'.$csv_line[$i].'</td>';
    }
    print "</tr>\n";
}

print '</table>';
fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
?>
```

But I have difficulties grouping them and getting values into variables (specific values from relevant cells)

Can somebody assist please?

thanks

Comment: Do you need the results as a web page or just the numbers?

Comment: You have to iterate over the data and process it however you need to process it - what have you tried to do? The code you posted just outputs it, it doesn't even attempt to do any aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the [official PHP Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) for fgetcsv.

```
$ratings = array()

if (($handle = fopen("bookings.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if(!isset($ratings[$data[1]]))
            $ratings[$data[1]] = $data[4];
        $ratings[$data[1]] += $data[4];
    }
    fclose($handle);

var_dump($ratings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your csv file should follow the pattern of your database. if your csv file columns is this Guestname , category, arrival, departure, rate this also should be the format of your database. I suggest to store your data on your db before displaying it.. try this code

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) 
    {
        //Import uploaded file to Database
        $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            $import= mysqli_query ($connect,"INSERT into table(Column_1,Column_2,Column_3,Column_4) 
            values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]')");

        }
           //fclose($handle);

    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('No File Selected')
</script>";
    }
```